easiest way to install web counter on offline kiosk system?
I am updating a series of old kiosks for a history museum.  Originally built around 15 years ago they would like me to add a page counter, among other changes, to determine how widely used the kiosks are.  The systems are being kept offline.
I am using Dreamweaver for the pages themselves.  I found sample .php code that sounds like it will do exactly what I need.  The hangup I'm running into is figuring out exactly what else I need to install - some google results talk about just installing php and using an included server, some talk about installing Apache and using that to access php.
I want to keep this as simple as possible; it's not something I do these days and I'm not getting paid much.  So, a couple questions:

Is a .php counter the easiest way to do what I'm after?

What's the easiest way to install and run .php on both a Mac development system and Windows 11 system that the kiosk is running on?


I currently have a line in my webpage calling the .txt file with .php:
<?php include "text_file_hit_counter.php"; ?>
I also have a .php file with the following code that I found here on StackOverflow:
<?
// Open the file for reading 
$fp = fopen("counterlog.txt", "r"); 
// Get the existing count 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); 
// Close the file 
fclose($fp); 
// Add 1 to the existing count 
$count = $count + 1; 
// Display the number of hits 
// If you don't want to display it, comment out this line 
echo "<p>Page views:" . $count . "</p>"; 
// Reopen the file and erase the contents 
$fp = fopen("counterlog.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($fp, $count); 
// Close the file 
fclose($fp); 
?>


"I want to keep this as simple as possible" You don't need a page counter, just grep the webserver logs.

Excuse the ignorance, but how/where do I do that? And do they get reset each time the system reboots? I need to make this work for museum staff who have even less knowledge than me.  And note that this is a system that is not online - I don't know the ins and outs of doing this on a system that's running its own server software.

"where do I do that?" It varies greatly by server, I can only tell you maybe start in /var/log. In general, any web server process will log a record of every incoming hit to a text file that follows a common format. You can then search that file for patterns to find how many times certain pages were served, etc. There are also lots of packages that will generate reports based on those logs.

"And do they get reset each time the system reboots?" Only if you've explicitly designed the system to do that.

Are the kiosks on a network? If so, you can pretty easily set up a daily/weekly cron that does your desired analysis and then emails/posts the results somewhere for consumption. There shouldn't be a need to physically walk to each kiosk to see its traffic.

(Oops, just noticed you said Windows host. In that case, I have no idea where the logs would be, but they're surely there somewhere.)

Alex, no, the kiosks are all stand-alone, no networking.

Well that does put a damper on things. Are they even using a web server process? Or just browsers hitting locally-stored files directly?

Locally stored files directly.  I was assuming to proceed with a counter I would need to install .php so I could create a counter using the built-in server I've read php contains.  Which is where my dilemma starts - I'm reading conflicting things about installing .php and am confused.  I create television programming schedules for a living.  Back when I created these websites (10+ years ago) I was doing graphic design and that's how I ended up with the project; my programming was one or two classes in college 30 years ago.

PHP does have a built-in server, but it should never be used in a production context, it's meant for development only. You'd be looking at a pretty significant design change of the kiosk configuration to convert from serverless to hosted PHP, just for the sake of one tiny script that does a page count. The minimal effort is probably doing it browser-side in JavaScript, storing the counts in local storage, like here. This way, only the page source has to change and the kiosk doesn't need to be touched.

ok, this makes sense I guess.  What do I need to install to use JavaScript like this?

Nothing, you'd just need to update the HTML page(s) being served, to add the JS source that stores/displays the record.

Thank you!  I'll be working on this tomorrow and hoping to get it functional.
